# Generators and relations for $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, finitely-generated, semisimple-lie-algebras

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t])$ can be thought of as matrix valued polynomials. As a vector space
$$\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t]) = \bigoplus_{k =0}^{\infty}\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C})t^k $$
and we have
$$[At^m, Bt^n] = [A,B]t^{n+m}$$
Since $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C})$ is simple, it can be readily seen that $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t])$ is generated by elements of $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C})t$. I would like to present this Lie algebra in as compact way as possible in terms of generators and relations. I have the following conjecture.
Consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ spanned by
$x, J(x)\;| x \in \mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C})$ with the following relations
\begin{cases}{}
& [x, J(y)] = J([x, y]) \\
& [x, [J(y), J(z)]] = [J(x), [y, J(z)]]
\end{cases}
Then $$\mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t])$$ More precisely, the following surjective homomorphism is in fact an isomorphism of the two algebra.
\begin{align*}
&\mathfrak{g} \twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak{sl}(N, \mathbb{C}[t])\\
&x \mapsto x\\
&J(x)\mapsto tx
\end{align*}
I have been trying to prove it directly, but to no avail. Is this true?

If it doesn't seem feasible to directly prove or disprove, is there any general theory to deal with these kind of questions?

Comment: In terms of generators, can you not do this with a set of generators for $\mathfrak{sl}(N,\mathbb{C})$ (perhaps a set of simple root vectors plus a lowest root vector) plus one regular semisimple element times $t$ (i.e. an element of the Cartan subalgebra that has non-zero bracket with each root vector) or is that not quite what you are after?

Comment: @Callum yeah, you're right in that the system I provided can further be simplified as you explained. The main difficulty though is in proving that the relations I wrote down are the only ones that we need to demand, to get the algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(N,\mathbb{C}[t])$ and not something bigger.
P.S. The reason I did not quite try to minimize the number of generators, is because there doesn't seem any nice canonical way to do so; for instance your idea includes an arbitrary choice of a regular semisimple element.

Comment: I found a paper (arXiv:1401.2143) which solves this problem in general case (although it seems to me their argument is slightly flawed). But anyway, I managed to answer my question for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ quite explicitly using one of their ideas, if anyone is interested I could post the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I have the follosing proof for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ case. However, I am not sure it's correct, because I am making weaker assumptions then in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2143) on which I am relying (Proposition 3.1). I would be very grateful if someone can point out any flaws in the argument or confirm it's sound.

## Generators of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}[t])$

Consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ spanned by
$e,f,h, J(e), J(f), J(h)$ with the following relations

\begin{cases}{}
& e,f,h \text{ satisfy the usual } \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \text{ relations} \\
(1) \label{first_rel}
& [x, J(y)] = J([x,y])
%\label{second_rel}
%& $[[x, J(y)], [J(z), J(w)]] = [[J(x), J(y)], [z, J(w)]]$
\end{cases}

Denote

\begin{align*}
& e_n := (\frac{1}{2}\text{ad}_{h_1})^n e\\
& f_n := (-\frac{1}{2}\text{ad}_{h_1})^n f\\
& h_n := [e, f_n]
\end{align*}

### Claim

$[x_k, y_l] = [x,y]_{k+l}$ where $x_n = (ae + bf + ch)_n := ae_n + bf_n+ ch_n$

#### Proof

We just need to check it for basis elements, more precisely that for ${k+l=n}$
\begin{align*}
& [e_k, e_l] = 0\\
& [f_k, f_l] = 0\\
& [h_k, h_l] = 0\\
& [e_k, h_l] = -2e_n\\
& [f_k, h_l] = 2f_n\\
& [e_k, f_l] = h_n
\end{align*}
Base case $n=1$ follow from (1). Assume that it's true for all $k+l < n$. First let's check that $[e_k, e_l] = [e_1, e_{n-1}]$ when $k, l > 0\;|\; k+l=n$. Indeed
$$0 = [h_s, [e_1, e_{n-s-1}]] = 2([e_{s+1}, e_{n-s-1}] + [e_1,e_{n-1}])$$
In particular $[e_{n-1}, e_1] = [e_1, e_{n-1}]$, which means that all the above are zero. Moreover
$$[e, e_n] = [e, [h_1, e_{n-1}]] = -2[e_1, e_{n-1}] + [h_1, [e, e_{n-1}]]=0$$
Similarly $[f_k, f_l] = 0$.

Let's continue writing similar identities
$$
[e_s, [h_1, h_{n-s-1}]] = 0 \Rightarrow [h_{n-s-1},e_{s+1}] = [h_1, e_{n-1}] = 2e_n
$$
and
$$[h_{n-s-1},f_{s+1}] = [h_1, f_{n-1}] = -2f_n$$
Now note that
$[h, e_n] =2e_n$ since $h$ and $h_1$ commute. Similarly $[h, f_n] = -2f_n$. Hence we have also proved that
$$
[f_k, h_l] = 2f_n \text{ and } [h_l, e_k] = 2 e_n
$$
It follows from definition that $[e_l, f_k] = h_n$. Indeed
$$
[ad_{h_1} e_{l-1}, f_k] = [e_{l-1}, -ad_{h_1} f_k] \Rightarrow
[e_l, f_k] = h_n
$$
It now only remains to prove that $[h_l, h_k] = 0$. But that easily follows from what we already derived
$$
[h_l, [e, f_k]] = 2[e_l, f_k] -2[e, f_{l+k}] = 2h_n - 2h_n = 0 
$$

### Corollary

The Lie algebra spanned by
$e, f, h, h_1$ satisfying relations
\begin{align*}
&[e,f] = h\\
& [h,e] = 2e\\
& [f, h] = 2f\\
& [h, h_1] = 0\\
& [e, f_1] = h_1
\end{align*}
is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}[t])$, where $e_1, f_1$ denote $\frac{1}{2}[h_1,e]$ and $\frac{1}{2}[f,h_1]$ respectively

Indeed, by virtue of Jacobi identity, we can derive all the neccessary relations to apply the above claim, e.g.
$$
 2[e, f_1] = [[e, f], h_1] + [f, [e, h_1]] = [f, [e, h_1]] = 2[e_1, f]
$$
$$[h, e_1] = [[h,h_1], e] + [h_1, 2e] = 2e_1$$
The consequence of the claim is that there is an isomomorphism from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ spanned by elements
$$J_n(x), x \in \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$$
with relations
$$
[J_k(x), J_l(y)] = J_{k+l}([x,y])
$$
It can be easily seen that these relations are satisfied in
$\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}[t])$
by elements
$xt^k, yt^l$
Moreover, the elements $xt^n$ span $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}[t])$, so the homomorphism ${\mathfrak{a}\to \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}[t])}$ is surjective, while comparing the dimensions of each degree (both algebras are clearly graded), we conclude that it is also injective.